# Chat application using PHP, MySQL and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have just started studying Ajax for making my own chat application using MySQL, PHP, JavaScript and Ajax.
I have almost made my application but the problem is that I have used `setInterval` so my box in which chat log is displayed it is fetched from the database every second and displayed,and this is inefficient.

Rather I want that the database is accessed only when there is some change in the database ,that is, when a user sends a message and the database is changed then only the database is fetched by other users message box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I asked this question a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458253/push-using-php-ajax-and-javascript-jquery) and got this answer which helped me immensely:

---

You are looking to PUSH data, which requires Websockets (see [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), [2](https://www.websocket.org), [3](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/WebSockets)). If you are using a Javascript library like Node.js, they have support for this.

What you'll need is a Websocket server (something that actually pushes).  There are Websocket servers for PHP (see [1](http://socketo.me), [2](http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets.html), [3](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets)). And the Websocket client (Javascript that receives the "push" and processes it). Please check out the links I've included for further research.

Comment: Actually it is a part of my college project and i am required to complete this using ajax only ,So can i make my project better,that is ,have some kind of a workaround for this set interval that i m using ,using ajax only?
I can pm u a copy of my project,if u have the time, will be truely greatful :)

Comment: If you'd like to pay me, sure I'll take a look! But I don't think that there's a way to do what you're looking for with AJAX only.